# String Interpolation in an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string-interpolation

I've got the following code:

```
const [answerObject, setAnswerObject] = useState({})

const answerItem = {"question_" + survey.id, selectedAnswer}
setAnswerObject(answerObject + answerItem)
```

And I'm trying to get this result:

```
answers = {
    question_1: 'text from answer 1',
    question_2: 'text from answer 2',
    question_3: 'text from answer 3',
}
```

However I'm having trouble interpolating it. I've tried a bunch of different methods with no luck. Any help or suggestions to format it properly would be great.

Comment: You should use an array, not an object with keys that contain a numeric index.

Comment: Your code has a lotto missing definitions/data.  What is `useState`, `survey`, `selectedAnswer`, `setAnswerObject`, `anserObject`?  None of these are explicitly defined

Comment: @Mike `useState`, and its return value are part of the react hooks API. They don't need to be defined in the question.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks! I didn't see the reactjs tag.  For some reason, I think I only saw `javascript` on the question at first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an interpolated string for an object key by using square brackets.

```
{ 
  [`question_${survey.id}`]: selectedAnswer 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can I ask one more thing. What if I want to add these items onto one another. For example the following doesn't work because it is not iterable. Is there another way?            setAnswer(answerObject => [...answerObject, answerItem])

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to merge objects together? There's a few ways. One is `Object.assign({}, answerObject, answerItem)`. Another is with the spread operator, e.g. `{ ...answerObject, ...answerItem }`